# Generate 404 Error in yii2

Tags: yii, error-handling

I am new to Yii framework and i want to generate 404 error if user not logged in.

Here is the code from view/item/index.php:

```
<?php
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
    {
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'Oops. Not logged in.'); 
    }
?>
```

But I get following Error:`Class 'app\models\CHttpException' not found`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHttpException if for Yii 1 .. for Yii2 you need HttpException

```
  <?php
      if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
      {
           throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404,'Oops. Not logged in.');
      }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

wrong here : "CHttpException"

CHttpException using in Yii1

in yii2 you use

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException('your message');
```

and first of controller 
`use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;`

Comment: Thank you. Can't vote your answer, with less then 15 reputations :(.

Comment: @FaizanAhmed no problem my friend